# Отсортировать groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Нужно отсортировать по столбцу `score` и оставить топ 3 лучших результата `sys_numb` для каждого `chb`.

```
d1 = {"chb":np.array(['1', '1', '2', '2', '2','3']), "sys_numb": np.array(['5', '15', '7', '9', '20', '25']), "score": np.array([.3, .13, .33, .21, .44, .22])}
d2 = {"chb":np.array(['1', '1', '2', '2', '2','3']), "sys_numb": np.array(['10', '12', '7', '9', '16', '17']), "score": np.array([.10, .12, .7, .78, .733, .123])}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(by = ['chb','sys_numb']).sum()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать такой вариант:

здесь оставляем как у вас есть

```
d1 = {"chb":np.array(['1', '1', '2', '2', '2','3']), "sys_numb": np.array(['5', '15', '7', '9', '20', '25']), "score": np.array([.3, .13, .33, .21, .44, .22])}
d2 = {"chb":np.array(['1', '1', '2', '2', '2','3']), "sys_numb": np.array(['10', '12', '7', '9', '16', '17']), "score": np.array([.10, .12, .7, .78, .733, .123])}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(by = ['chb','sys_numb']).sum()
```

далее:

```
new_df = df3.sort_values('score').groupby(level=0).tail(3).sort_index().reset_index()

>>> new_df
  chb sys_numb  score
0   1       12  0.120
1   1       15  0.130
2   1        5  0.300
3   2       16  0.733
4   2        7  1.030
5   2        9  0.990
6   3       17  0.123
```

в `tail` вставляем нужное значение (количество топа)